# Google Apps Script - Parsing Data from Gmail Body Text with Identical Subject Line

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this Google Apps script to extract and parse data fields from the body text of gmail messages. I've modified the script so that it works for the fields I have in my e-mails. However, I've discovered that it only works when e-mails have different subject lines. For example, if I have five e-mails all with different subject lines, the script will create 5 rows in a Google spreadsheet, one for each e-mail. But if I have 5 e-mails all with the same subject line, I only get one row for the oldest email in the inbox. Does anyone know how I can modify this script so that the subject line can be the same for all e-mails? Thanks!

```
/* Based on https://gist.github.com/Ferrari/9678772 */

function parseEmailMessages(start) {

start = start || 0;

var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

// Get the first email message of a threads
var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  subject = message.getSubject(),
  content = message.getPlainBody();

// Get the plain text body of the email message
// You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

// Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
if (content) {

  tmp = content.match(/Name:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var username = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/Title:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var title = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/Organization:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var organization = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/City:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var city = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/State:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var state = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/country:\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var country = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/E-mail:\s*([\s\S]+)/);
  var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No comment';

  sheet.appendRow([username, title, organization, city, state, country, email]);

} // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `message = threads[i].getMessages()[0]` retrieves only the first (oldest) message in the thread, i.e. index 0 of the threads array. You want to iterate over each message in the thread so you'll need to retrieve the whole thread into a new array.  In short, lose the array index after the `getMessages()` call.
Try this logic:

```
threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100)
for (i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  messages = threads[i].getMessages()
  for (j = 0; j < thread.length; j++)
    subject = messages[j].getSubject()
    content = messages[j].getPlainBody()
    etc...
```

Comment: I'm still getting only one row of data.

Comment: Very strange! I have run both your code & my update as a test get a different number of rows for each implementation.  Are your emails with the same subject appearing as threaded? What to you see if you record the email subject along with your other output? Is only retrieving the first 100 threads contributing to what you're seeing?

Comment: Well, I decided to just change the code in the php file that mails the online form data so that each subject line is unique (I added the user's submitted e-mail address to the subject line of each email.) This solves the problem and I now get each e-mail in its own row. Thanks for your help!